# Interpolating inside a nested backquote expression

Tags: backquote

Consider this macro helper function that returns a backquote expression:

```
(defun make-headers ()
  `(:headers `(("Authorization" . ,(get-auth)))))
```

This returns the list `` (:headers `(("Authorization" . ,(get-auth)))) ``, suitable for interpolating into a macro expansion.

Now I want to add an argument which, if not nil, will be used as-is as an additional header; if nil, the original list should be returned.  I can't figure out how to interpolate down multiple backquote levels.  I thought multiple commas might work, like:

```
(defun make-headers (content-type)
  `(:headers `(("Authorization" . ,(get-auth))
               ,,@(when content-type (list (cons "Content-Type" content-type))))))
```

...but this doesn't work as I expected.  The best I can do is to awkwardly sort-of duplicate what the original internal backquote was doing:

```
(defun make-headers (content-type)
  `(:headers (append (list (cons "Authorization" (get-auth)))
                     ,(when content-type (list 'list (list 'cons "Content-Type" content-type)))))))
```

That's pretty terrible, though.  Isn't there a simpler way to interpolate down multiple backquote levels?

For an example simpler than the above, consider this:

```
(let ((z :z)) `(:foo :bar `(:x :y ,z)))
```

This evaluates to

```
(:foo :bar `(:x :y ,z))
```

So how about:

```
(let ((z :z)) `(:foo :bar `(:x :y ,,z)))
```

That produces:

```
(:foo :bar `(:x :y ,:z))
```

How can I produce just:

```
(:foo :bar `(:x :y :z))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is maybe as good as it gets:

```lisp
(let ((z :z)) `(:foo :bar (backquote (:x :y ,z))))
```

That gives you this:

```lisp
(:foo :bar (backquote (:x :y :z)))
```

But maybe someone has a better suggestion. I have a feeling that Elisp doesn't quite have what it takes in this regard. Other Lisp dialects might work better for this.